# YouTube Connector Tridion Integration Framework

Tags: external-integrations, sites-9.1

I've been off the forums for a while.  I was wondering if there is a new version of the YouTube connector built with the Tridion Integration framework.  The only one I found on the tridion appstore is this old verison.  https://appstore.sdl.com/web-content-management/app/youtube-ecl-provider/631/
Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK - still old ELC provider supported in the same way as before. I'm not sure youtube connector available based on new **Tridion Integration Framework**.

For your reference, @Niclas created a nice blog about [Developing connectors using the new Tridion Integration Framework](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/developing-connectors-using-the-new-tridion-integration-framework#_cptype=root).

I hope it helps.